# Proving that $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ has a pole of order 3 at $z_{0} = i$, $p(z)$ has a pole of order 4 and $q(z)$ has a pole of order 7 at $z_{0} = i$.

Tags: complex-numbers

Here is my work so far.

Since $p(z)$ has a pole of order $4$ at $z_{0} = 1$ we can write

$$p(z) = \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-i)^{4}}$$

where $\phi(z)$ is non-zero and analytic at $z_{0}=i$.

Similarly

Since $q(z)$ has a pole of order $7$ at $z_{0} = 1$ we can write

$$q(z) = \frac{\gamma(z)}{(z-i)^{7}}$$

where $\gamma(z)$ is non-zero and analytic at $z_{0}=i$.

Next I divided the two equations since we wanted to figure out the order of $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$.

What I got was

$$\frac{p(z)}{q(z)} = \frac{\phi(z)(z-i)^{3}}{\gamma(z)}$$

Now I'm stuck because if the $(z-i)^{3}$ was in the denominator then I would be able to conclude that $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ had a pole of order $3$ but it is in the numerator. I was wondering how do I proceed from here?

Comment: This would make much more sense if you had "... if p(z) and q(z) have zeroes of order 4 and 7 at...", are you sure about the text?

Comment: @polettix I'm doing this question from a final exam practice problems that the professor gave. The wording is what I wrote up in the title.

Comment: then your conclusions are right and are the same as Riju's... you end up with an order 3 zero in $z = i$, not a pole. Might it be that the text of the exam has a typo and it was corrected just at the beginning of the exam? E.g. that $ \frac{p(z)}{q(z)} $ should actually be $\frac{q(z)}{p(z)}$

Answer (score 0):

Actually $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ has removable singularity at z=i and if you do remove the singularity then it will have a zero of order 3.

Comment: I get the part about having a removable singularity, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say "if you do remove the singularity it will have a zero of order 3".

Comment: What I mean is that is if you have removable singularity of a function at a point a then you can define a value at that point such that the function becomes analytic at that point. And how should you extend the function? By defining zero at i since then only your function will become continuos. And after you define that you will see that you have a zero of order 3. at i.